# BigQuery - Help w/Loop and/or Recursive Logic

Tags: sql, loops, google-bigquery

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I'm trying to build retention/degradation curves in BigQuery - I'm adapting old code used in Vertica, but I can't seem to get the logic right in BigQuery.

The basic data-structure would be something like below

```
    Count   Degredation
   1 567    1
   2 436    0.7689594356
   3 423    0.9701834862
   4 376    0.8888888889
   5 305    0.8111702128
   6 234    0.7672131148
   7 180    0.7692307692
   8 143    0.7944444444
   9 127    0.8881118881
   10 100   0.7874015748
   11   0.7654321
   12   0.5463234
   13   0.9876543
   14   0.876435463
   15   0.9865432
   16   1
   17   0.456789
```

What I am trying to do is to take the Count (Column A) and populate the projected values in the blank rows. Basically if  this was in Excel it would be calculated A11 * B12, A12*B13 ect...

Trouble getting the Recursive CTE implemented correctly

Edit: I've attempted to use Exponential of the LN but it leaves me with floating point errors where I can't resolve all by converting to int64.

```
exp(sum(ln(nullif(cast(renewal_count_rate as int64),0))) over (partition by subscription_number_id order by period asc rows unbounded preceding)) as renewal_count_curve,
        exp(sum(ln(nullif(cast(potential_renewal_count_rate as int64),0))) over (partition by subscription_number_id order by period asc rows unbounded preceding)) as potential_renewal_count_rate_curve,
        exp(sum(ln(nullif(cast(pre_tax_amount_rate as int64),0))) over (partition by subscription_number_id order by period asc rows unbounded preceding)) as pre_tax_amount_rate_curve,
        exp(sum(ln(nullif(cast(net_pre_tax_amount_rate as int64),0))) over (partition by subscription_number_id order by period asc rows unbounded preceding)) as net_pre_tax_amount_rate_curve,
        exp(sum(ln(nullif(cast(refunded_amount_rate as int64),0))) over (partition by subscription_number_id order by period asc rows unbounded preceding)) as refunded_amount_rate_curve,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
select *, cast(
     first_value(Count) over win * 
     exp(sum(ln(Degredation)) over win) 
  as int64) as Prediction
from your_table
window win as (order by ts)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: So I've tried that approach before, it works great in Vertica but I get tons of floating point errors in BigQuery. I should have mentioned that in the original comment

Comment: your added example is not how it is in my answer. have you tried exactly as in my answer?